# Enviar e-mail usando ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, envio-de-email

Como posso enviar e-mail usando ASP.NET MVC? Tem alguma opção de enviar sem especificar o SMTP parecido com o `mail()` do PHP?

Comment: Estou achando a pergunta muito ampla mas vou tentar responder porque respondem coisas amplas assim. Não tenho como te dizer qual é a melhor porque seria só minha opinião. Mas pode pelo menos dizer algo mais específico sobre o que é a dúvida? O que você sabe fazer? Ou o que já fez? Tem alguma importância ser ASP.Net MVC? Por que? Qual?

Comment: Sua resposta atende o que eu queria.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma que me parece interessante é esta:

```
public bool Mail(MailAddress to, MailAddress from, string sub, string body) {
    var me = new EmailBusiness();
    var m = new MailMessage() {
        Subject = sub,
        Body = body,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };
    to = new MailAddress("endereço@de.email", "Nome");
    m.To.Add(to);
    m.From = new MailAddress(from.ToString());
    m.Sender = to;
    var smtp = new SmtpClient {
        Host = "url.do.servidor",
        Port = 587,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("usuario", "senha"),
        EnableSsl = true
    };
    try {
        smtp.Send(m);
    } catch (Exception e) { //não faça isto, por favor, é só um exemplo
        return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/SendMail.cs).

Achei ela em [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31716759/221800) e adaptei. Lá tem mais informações se quiser incluir em uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC. Mas eu entendo que o foco da pergunta é o envio em si e não o ASP.NET MVC. Obviamente ela pode ser melhorada.

A pergunta e a outra resposta na mesma página tem uma forma um pouco diferente.

Note que o `mail()` do PHP usa um servidor de SMTP. Não tem como enviar sem ter um. A não ser que você escreva um código ou pegue uma biblioteca que seja um servidor SMTP. Em geral isto não é uma boa ideia.

Answer (score 5):

Sim. Por exemplo, o [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). Montei um Helper pra ele assim:

```
public static class SendGridHelper
{
    public static async Task EnviarEmail(String assunto, String mensagemHtml, String mensagemText)
    {
        // Cria o objeto de e-mail
        var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();

        // Remetente
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("meu@email.com.br");

        List<String> recipients = new List<String>
            {
                @"Cigano Morrison Mendez <cigano@stackoverflowemportugues.com>"
            };

        myMessage.AddTo(recipients);
        myMessage.Subject = assunto;

        myMessage.Html = mensagemHtml;
        myMessage.Text = mensagemText;

        // Você pode mandar por credenciais...
        // var username = "usuario";
        // var pswd = "senha";
        // var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, pswd);
        //var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);

        // ...ou por chave de API
        var transportWeb = new Web("MinhaChaveDeApi");

        // Finalmente, envia.
        await transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);
    }
}
```

O SendGrid [é gratuito para até 12 mil e-mails](https://sendgrid.com/pricing). Tem painel de gerenciamento e é bastante resiliente a spam.