# Dúvida quanto ao uso do SPA Template do VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, single-page-application

Preciso fazer uma rotina para enviar email, através de um formulário que fiz, usando o Template do SPA do VS2015. Coloquei dois botões, Cancelar e Enviar. A dúvida não está no código do email, mas como atribuir o Click do botão ao meu código no Controller e também os campos. Estou usando SPA para aprendizado, por isso usei o template do VS2015 e fui alterando conforme minha necessidade.

Essa é inha View(CSHTML)

```
@model Projeto.Models.ContactEmail
@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "Email", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Enviar email.</h4>
    <hr />

    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Assunto, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Assunto, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Texto, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Texto, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancelar" />
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Aqui é o código da Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Projeto.Controllers
{
    public class EmailController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Email
        public ActionResult Email()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EnviarEmail()
        {
            //Aqui deve ir o código de tudo, enviar email e etc
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

Essa é a model do Email:

```
public class ContactEmail
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Assunto")]
        public string Assunto { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Texto")]
        public string Texto { get; set; }
    }
```

Essa é minha rotina de envio de email:

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult EnviarEmail(ContactEmail contactEmail)
        {
            WebMail.SmtpServer = "mail19.redehost.com.br";
            WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
            //WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
            WebMail.From = contactEmail;
            WebMail.UserName = "teste@meudomino.com.br";
            WebMail.Password = "tested123";
            WebMail.Send(contactEmail.Email, contactEmail.Assunto, contactEmail.Texto);

            return View(contactEmail);
        }
```

Onde `contactEmail` é o email digitado na página pelos usuários da mesma.
teste@meudomino.com.br -> É para onde estou enviando o email. Já troquei(Inverti) e continua sem enviar. Com a configuração acima, me dá esse erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que o botão cancelar deve fazer?

Comment: @Randrade, ele iria cancelar o envio, limpando os campos.

Comment: Eu peguei uma resposta do Cigano em outra thread e consegui resolver a questão da "conversa" entre Controller e View(Razor). Isso me ajudou a resolver a pergunta.

Comment: Você não poderia apenas limpar os campos ou atualizar a página? Um simples botão faria o que deseja `<a href="@Url.Action("Email", "Email")" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancelar</a>`. Se você não vai ter nenhuma ação, não vejo a necessidade de fazer um `POST` para isso.

Comment: @Randrade, o seu comentário acima resolveu a questão de limpar o form.

Comment: Altere seu `form` para `@using (Html.BeginForm("EnviarEmail", "Email", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))`. Note que está passando a `Action` **Email**, mas o nome em seu controller é **EnviarEmail**.

Answer (score 2):

Veja que você tem todo seu formulário na `View` dentro de:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "Email", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    //Seu form
}
```

Então você pode fazer isso no seu `Controller` para verificar se um `Submit` está sendo executado:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EnviarEmail()
{
    if (Request.Form["Submit"] != null)
    {
        if (Request.Form["Submit"].ToString() == "Enviar")
        {
            //Aqui deve ir o código de tudo, enviar email e etc
        }
        else
        {
            //Outro tratamento
        }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dá pra usar também um argumento nomeado:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EnviarEmail(string submit)
    {
        switch (submit)
        {
            case "Enviar":
               ...
            case "Cancelar":
               ...
            default:
               ...
        }

        //Aqui deve ir o código de tudo, enviar email e etc
        return View(model);
    }
```

Apenas certifique-se que cada botão tem o atributo `name`:

```
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancelar" />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer apenas limpar o formulário, eu não vejo a necessidade de fazer um `POST` para isso. Você pode apenas atualizar a página ou "resetar" o `form` resolveria o seu problema.

Para atualizar a página, pode fazer algo parecido com isso em seu botão cancelar:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Email", "Email")" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancelar</a>
```

Caso queira apenas limpar os campos, pode resetar o `form`. Um exemplo seria alterar o seu botão cancelar para isso:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancelar" onclick="this.form.reset();"/>
```

[Veja um exemplo no .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K8XXxj)

Answer (score 2):

Gostaria de atenta-lo para um possivel problema, no teu `Html.BeginForm` você definiu o Action como `Email`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "Email", ...
```

Mas no teu Controller você o Action se chama `EnviarEmail`:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> EnviarEmail()
```

Então presumo que o correto seria para cancelar:

```
 <a href="@Url.Action("EnviarEmail", "Email")" class="btn btn-danger"> Cancelar</a>
```

E o correto do Form seria:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EnviarEmail", "Email", ...
```

O que provavelmente causou o erro em: [Enviar e-mail com formulário de contato em SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203953/3635)

Comment: Guilherme, ao enviar após as correções que você sugeriu e está certo, dá esse erro: O nome remoto não pôde ser resolvido: 'smtp.meudominio.com.br'. Liguei para o host que hospeda a página(RedeHost) e lá eles me disseram que o SmtpServer está correto. Pesquisando na Internet o erro pode ser smtpserver errado ou não configurado. Tem alguma sugestão?

Comment: @pnet a porta `WebMail.SmtpPort = 2550;` está correta? Se o teu servidor de SMTP necessita de SSL tente a resposta do @bigown https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/84247/3635