# Enviar email ao cadastrar form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda de vocês, eu tenho um form em meu sistema, preciso que quando eu cadastra-lo envie um email para um usuario.

Quando eu clico em salvar entro neste post para salvar os dados.

```
[HttpPost]
public void EventosAdversos(EventosAdversos obj)
{
    var hospitalId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("hid"));
    var usuarioId = int.Parse(Cookies.GetCookie("uid"));

    obj.HospitalId = hospitalId;
    obj.StatPree = 1;
    obj.UsuarioId = usuarioId;

    if (obj.EaId == 0)
    {
        var eaId = _eventosAdversosService.NovoEaId(obj.PatientId, hospitalId);
        obj.EaId = eaId;
    }

    _eventosAdversosService.Add(obj);
}
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Cria uma classe EmailService e encapsula os métodos que você quer usar para o envio. No fim da sua rotina você chamaria, caso sucesso, "EmailService.enviarEmailCadastro();". Detalhes do envio você encontra (aqui)[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/630/como-posso-enviar-um-e-mail-pelo-gmail] e (aqui)[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/84239/enviar-e-mail-usando-asp-net-mvc]

Comment: http://netcoders.com.br/aplicando-solid-com-c-srp/

Answer (score 1):

Crie uma classe para enviar email e chame no seu método aí.

Segue o exemplo:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;

...
try
{

   SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient("my.smtp.exampleserver.net");

    // set smtp-client with basicAuthentication
    mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   System.Net.NetworkCredential basicAuthenticationInfo = new
      System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
   mySmtpClient.Credentials = basicAuthenticationInfo;

   // add from,to mailaddresses
   MailAddress from = new MailAddress("test@example.com", "TestFromName");
   MailAddress to = new MailAddress("test2@example.com", "TestToName");
   MailMessage myMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(from, to);

   // add ReplyTo
   MailAddress replyto = new MailAddress("reply@example.com");
   myMail.ReplyToList.Add(replyTo);

   // set subject and encoding
   myMail.Subject = "Test message";
   myMail.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

   // set body-message and encoding
   myMail.Body = "<b>Test Mail</b><br>using <b>HTML</b>.";
   myMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
   // text or html
   myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

   mySmtpClient.Send(myMail);
}

catch (SmtpException ex)
{
  throw new ApplicationException
    ("SmtpException has occured: " + ex.Message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
```

Obs.: vc vai precisar usar a lib `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`

Comment: Muito bom, simples e direto sua resposta.